# Timerを使ったアニメーションで予定外の動きに困っております。

Tags: swift

タイマーを利用してtoyImageCustomViewを4秒おきに生成し、画面の外まで移動したら、
そのtoyImageCustomViewを消していく。と言う、アニメーションをやりたいのですが、

なぜか、最初のtoyImageCustomViewが画面の外で消えると同時に最後のtoyImageCustomViewも
画面の途中にもかかわらず、消えてしまいます。

この原因がどうしてもわかりません。

どなたかご教授願えないでしょうか？
よろしくお願いいたします。

[image: タイマーを動かすコードです。]
[image: タイマーによって動かすアニメーションです。]

Comment: コードを提示するときは画像ではなく、テキストを使用してください。自分の環境にコピペして動作を再現する、検索をかけて綴りミスを発見する…等々テキストとして提示していただくことで問題点がはるかに見つけやすくなります。(コードとして見やすくするための整形方法もヘルプ等を見ておためしください。)

Answer (score 1):

275行めでインスタンス変数の`toyImageCustomView`をタイマーでこのメソッドが呼ばれるたびに上書きしているので、`toyImageCustomView`に入っているのはアニメーションで順に動かしている最後のビューということになります。
（4秒ごとに呼ばれて１つのアニメーションが30秒なので、７枚めか8枚めのビューになります。）

そして最初のビューのアニメーションが終了して、`completion`ハンドラで**インスタンス変数の**`toyImageCustomView`を削除しているので、消えるのは最初のビューではなくて、最後のビューになります。

とりあえず、簡単に修正するのなら、`toyImageCustomView`をインスタンス変数にするのではなく、ローカル変数にして、クロージャに毎回キャプチャして、キャプチャした変数に対してメソッドを呼べばいいと思います。